# Raspberry Pi 3 pyaduio does not detect any devices

Tags: python-3.x, pyaudio

I have installed pyaudio (latest as of today Oct 16, 2017) in my Raspberry PI 3 with "sudo pip3 install pyaudio". I am running "python3" for the code below:

```
import pyaudio

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
print("Number of devices={}".format(p.get_device_count()))
```

This prints Number of devices=0

Does anyone have the same problem? Need help to resolve this issue.

Additional info: "`lsusb`" prints all the devices. 
I am able to see the device in `alsamixer`. I am able to test that device works. Looks like pyaudio & python3 may have something to do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The above issue was happening with Raspberry NOOBS image.

I ended up downloading the RASPBIAN image and finally it is working though pyaudio is printing too many warning messages.